# Converting a struct array to string array including one of the property of the struct

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a struct array `Imgs` and it includes following properties of image files inside each struct.

```
name
date
byte
isdir
datenum
```

now I want to create a new string array `img_names` that includes the only names of the above struct array. I am really a newbie about matlab and I don't get how to do it.

So I want to have a array like in that structure.

```
img_names[1] = 'file-1.jpg'

img_names[2] = 'file-2.jpg'

img_names[3] = 'file-3.jpg'

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img_names = arrayfun(@(x) x.name,Imgs,'uni',false)
```

produces a cell array containing the names. You can then access each name using:

```
img_names{1}
img_names{2}
% ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>> img_names=sprintf('%s\n',Imgs.name);
```

Comment: if I do that it will pass all the names to first index location but I wan to put each name to next index of each other.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  Can you post a more accurate example of your data and what you would like it to look like?